# what is wrong with this conditional (if-else) execution in batch script?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am testing some small scripts that I have. This particular one is driving me crazy. In my mind it should work, but it is not doing what I thought it would/should.

```
@echo off
echo testing the issue
echo.

ECHO Checking the log file for errors...
echo %errorlevel%
FINDSTR /C:"open failed" C:\automatic_deployment\test1.txt 
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO Deployment failed.
pause
GOTO quit) else (GOTO TSTErrChecking1)

:TSTErrChecking1
FINDSTR /C:"does not exist" C:\automatic_deployment\test1.txt
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO Deployment failed.
pause
GOTO quit) else (GOTO TSTErrChecking2)

:TSTErrChecking2
FINDSTR /C:"Logon failed" C:\automatic_deployment\test1.txt 
echo %errorlevel%
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO Deployment failed.
pause
GOTO quit) else ( GOTO TSTErrChecking3)

:TSTErrChecking3
FINDSTR /C:"Failure" C:\automatic_deployment\test1.txt 
echo %errorlevel% 
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
ECHO Deployment failed.
pause
GOTO quit) else ( GOTO TSTErrChecking4)

:TSTErrChecking4
FINDSTR /C:"RC (return code) = 0" C:\automatic_deployment\test1.txt 
echo %errorlevel%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
ECHO Deployment was successful.
pause
GOTO quit) ELSE (
ECHO Deployment failed.
pause
GOTO quit)


:quit
exit
```

As you can see I am using "FINDSTR" to find certain words/strings from a small test1.txt file and act accordingly. I want it to say "deployment failed" and quit asap if it sees any "fail"/ "does not exist"/"open failed". If it cannot find anyone of those above and finds  the "RC (return code) = 0"  I want it to say it was "successful".

So, i put all those test words and strings in my test1.txt file and tested the batch script, but it keeps skipping (i think) all those fail hints/words and keeps saying it was successful. Plz, help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just didn't have the matching strings to search for. I didn't know that FINDSTR looked for EXACTLY the same case letters when searching and comparing. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it could be that you already have an `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable defined in your environment

Read

Raymond Chen's  *`ERRORLEVEL` is not `%ERRORLEVEL%`*  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx

and then try

```
FINDSTR /C:"RC (return code) = 0" test.txt
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Deployment failed.
```

Comment: @PA.- thanks for the heads up :) However, I tested what I had, and it worked. I just didn't have the matching strings to search for. I didn't know that FINDSTR looked for EXACTLY the same case letters when searching and comparing. That was the problem.